# "attract somebody to do something"

Tags: word-usage

As per [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/attract), the usage of "attract" is:

> **attract sb to sth** They are trying to attract more holiday-makers to the area.

Is it grammatically correct to use "attract sb to *do* sth"?

> The government has made lots of policies to **attract specialists to immigrate**.

Comment: I don't think this is the verb you are looking for. Maybe you want *incentivize* or *convince* or *persuade*.

Comment: The "standard" verb for the cited context is probably ***encourage***. But it's all a matter of opinion (though I'm sure *most* people's opinion would be that ***attract*** isn't really suitable here).